Roll back partially correct data if a blocker is reported after the latest build deployment
I am interested in understanding the scenarios in which a build has been deployed to production, and after a few days, a critical issue arises that necessitates reverting to the previous build number through the CI/CD pipeline. The challenge lies in handling the database, as the codebase is tightly coupled with it. What are the best strategies and approaches for rolling back changes, considering that the persisted data may be partially correct? How should this scenario be managed?
